# Why when trying to play animation clip nothing happen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What i want is when running the game that the animation clip will start playing automatically.

I added to the Main Camera a Animation component.
Added in the Inspector to the Animation the clip file name Camera_Sign003 also set the Animations size to 1 and added there the same clip Camera_Sign003.
Also i set to true the Play Automatically.

I also attached a script to the Main Camera:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraPoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animation anim;
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
        anim.Play(anim.clip.name);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(anim.clip.length);
    }
}
```

And i checked with a break point it's getting to the line anim.Play....And the length is 10 but nothing happen after 10 seconds.

The animation is a short clip moving the camera from point to point.

The Main Camera is child under ThirdPersonController.

[image: Animation]

Answer (score 0):

The `Animation` component is a legacy component and shouldn't be used unless you need to support a legacy tool or project.

What you really need is an `Animator` component with an `Animation Controller` for the object. The easiest way to set this up is by selecting the object you want to animate (e.g. Main Camera), opening the 'Animation' window, and clicking the 'Create' button there.

The new animation created will play automatically and loop by default. 
More information can be found here: [Unity - Manual: Creating a New Animation Clip](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-CreatingANewAnimationClip.html)

[image: Create Animator]

Comment: Ok i created now new animation clip. Removed the Animation component from the Main Camera. In the Animator component i added as Controller the main camera. I'm not using the script now. When running the game in the Animator window i see the animation clip state and i see it's like playing it i see the blue bar inside running. But in fact in the game window nothing i don't see the recorded clip. I'm not getting any errors or warnings.

Comment: More then that i added new empty GameObject added to it a Animator component in the Inspector to the Animator component i added the Main Camera as controller. Then opened the Animation window created new animation clip. And when running the game i see in the Animator window that it's playing the clip but it's not showing it in the game view.

Comment: Strange. If it looks like it's playing, then perhaps it's not playing the right animation? Try looking at the Animation Controller using the 'Animator' window and selecting the animation state that the 'Entry' state points to. That should contain the animation clip you want to play. For more information, see https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationOverview.html

Comment: Ok i found the problem. Not sure why but the problem was that the Main Camera was child of the ThirdPersonController. Once i moved the camera to the top to be none child it's working.